# How to use Bootstrap DateTimePicker and KnockOut with UTC only

Tags: knockout.js, twitter-bootstrap-3, datetimepicker

I have a databound DateTimePicker widget using Knockout.  The initial time provided by the server is in UTC.  When the DateTimePicker is updated on the client it appears to show the correct date and time, but behind the scenes it seems to be assuming that the datetime is local, so when I do an update via the UI, and then sync with the server the datetime has been shitfed by +7:00 (my local timezone is Mountain Time).

How do I configure DateTimePicker (4.17.37 - https://github.com/Eonasdan/bootstrap-datetimepicker) to only use UTC?

Answer (score 0):

The problem seemed to be that because the DateTimePicker depends on the moment.js (http://momentjs.com/) library, all DateTimes where being converted to the default browser time zone.

The fix involved including the moment-timezone-with-data.js library (http://momentjs.com/timezone/), and then setting the default zone to UTC via:

```
moment.tz.setDefault("UTC");
```